# Oracle 11g Application express login credential error

Tags: sql, oracle

while i am login in Oracle 11g Application express in windows 11, its show attached error Please help me to rectify this error.[Oracle Application Express error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r19O.jpg)

Comment: Has a user with that name been created in that workspace? Is the password you’re giving correct? Either way, you really ought to upgrade both the database and APEX (which won’t solve this problem but will be good in general)

Comment: Connect to the **Internal** workspace as **admin** user. Check which workspaces you have. Check which developers you have, and which workspaces they are assigned to. If necessary, change their password so that you could establish connection

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Users in Application Express (APEX) are not the same as database users. So just because you have a database user called HR, does not mean you automatically have an APEX user called HR.

As mentioned by Littlefoot, you'll need to log in to the admin part of APEX to see/create accounts that you can use to login with.  Head to Workspace => Developers & Users to create an account under the HR workspace.

Also, that version of APEX looks waaayyy out of date. I'd strongly recommend that you get a more recent version from the downloads section at apex.oracle.com